# Query 2 fields Date Range Overlap Date Range

Tags: date, ms-access, range, overlap

So this is a new one, I am thinking.  We have an Access query with 2 date fields fdate1 and fdate2.  The fdate1 is always the first date, and fdate2 is always the second.  The two are a range.  What we need to do is query the table to find all the records where the record is at any point in the year 2010.  So for instance, here is some pretend data:

Fname fdate1 fdate2
John  2/18/2008 5/08/2014
Mary 1/6/2010 6/21/2010
Jane 9/25/2010 4/13/2012

We need to know any records that involve the date range of 1/1/2010 - 12/31/2010.  As you can see, the above records all match, but because they are 2 separate fields, I am not sure how to find that those 2 columns represent a date range and that date range does or does not overlap with the date range criteria.  Make sense?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to place the criteria `>DateSerial(2010,1,1)` on `fdate2`, and `<DateSerial(2011,1,1)` on `fdate1`.

Answer (score 1):

select * from tablename
Where (fdate1 between '1/1/2010' and '12/31/2010') OR (fdate2 '1/1/2010' and '12/31/2010')